# Easiest way to create a word wrap from a string in swift

Tags: string, swift, word-wrap

What is the easiest way to create a word wrap in Swift from a string? Let's say I have a string with 150 characters and I wish to start a new line every 50 characters. Your thoughts are most appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried, and how was it deficient?  And do you care *where* lines get broken (i.e. mid-word, however you'd define a 'word')?

Comment: Word wrap where? You can use NSAttributedString with NSParagraphStyle.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I was unaware of the NSParagraphStyle class.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
extension String {
    public func wrap(columns: Int = 80) -> String {
        let scanner = NSScanner(string: self)

        var result = ""
        var currentLineLength = 0

        var word: NSString?
        while scanner.scanUpToCharactersFromSet(NSMutableCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet(), intoString: &word), let word = word {
            let wordLength = word.length

            if currentLineLength != 0 && currentLineLength + wordLength + 1 > columns {
                // too long for current line, wrap
                result += "\n"
                currentLineLength = 0
            }

            // append the word
            if currentLineLength != 0 {
                result += " "
                currentLineLength += 1
            }
            result += word as String
            currentLineLength += wordLength
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

With tests:

```
func testWrapSimple() {
    let value = "This is a string that wraps!".wrap(10)
    XCTAssertEqual(value, "This is a\nstring\nthat\nwraps!")
}

func testWrapLongWords() {
    let value = "Thesewordsare toolongforasingle line".wrap(10)
    XCTAssertEqual(value, "Thesewordsare\ntoolongforasingle\nline")
}
```

Comment: FYI, `scanUpToCharacters` is deprecated in macOS 10.15.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a crude swift word wrap program. Feel free to comment - because everyday is a school day!

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var string1: String = "I think this is a good word wrap method, but I must try many times!"


    override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let arr = split(string1, { $0 == " "}, maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false)
    println(arr)

    for words in arr  {



        println("variable string1 has \(countElements(words)) characters!")

                        }

    var firstThirtyFive: String =  string1.substringToIndex(advance(string1.startIndex, 35))

        println(firstThirtyFive)

    var arr2 = split(firstThirtyFive, { $0 == " "}, maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false)

     println(arr2.count)

    var removed = arr2.removeLast()

    println(arr2)

    println(removed)




    var fromThirtyFive:String = string1.substringFromIndex(advance(string1.startIndex,35))


     println(fromThirtyFive)

    var arr3 = split(fromThirtyFive, { $0 == " "}, maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false)

    var removeFirst = arr3.removeAtIndex(0)

    var newWord:String = removed + removeFirst


    println(removeFirst)

    println(arr3)

    println(newWord)

    arr3.insert(newWord, atIndex: 0)

    println(arr3)


    let res1 = join(" ", arr2)

    let res2 = join(" ", arr3)

    println(res1)
    println(res2)






}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```